# Java OOP pattern question, how would an experienced programmer approach this type of complexity?

Tags: java, oop

I have a set of auto-generated java classes. 
The generated classes are each are named like:

- MappingOneToTwo
- MappingOnetoThree
- MappingThreeToOne
- ... etc

I have a considerable amount of them, and they are subject to changing in the following ways.

- New Mappings will be created
- Old Mappings might be eliminated
- Mapping Implementation might change

With that said, I'm using a cli front end I made using [picoli](https://picocli.info/).  I'm within the same package, but have the generated code and my written code in separate directories, my build works and the resulting jar has my main class in  manifest.

Each Mapping class has 1 or more parameters in a method named `run()`.

- input, connection
- input, connection, output
- input, input, connection, output
- connection, output

Simply put, what I do with these classes I can freely determine, I just need to use the classes in some manner.

How should the Java code be approached?

Comment: *I have generated code with a proprietary program* and *I have a considerable amount of them, and they are subject to changing*... time to update your resume. This will not end well.

Comment: In general, I would suggest not making one-to-one ETL code and standardize over a unified PubSub-like platform that all "mappings" understand. Take a look at Apache Nifi or Streamsets for inspiration. Nifi for example, operates over what are called "FlowFiles", which hold single events along with some metadata about the event. A batch of events can be sent to any other "processor", and forwarded, filtered, split, transformed, etc.

Comment: I simply don't have the business complexity to justify something meant for larger data. This is not a data at scale problem, it's a high complexity problem.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, What would you suggest for mapping arbitrary CSV and XML to a database?  Do you have an answer? I'm very willing to consider alternate options.

Comment: *Do you have an answer? I'm very willing to consider alternate options.* The problem is the "subject to change" aspect and the large number of them. [Frutiger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frutiger_(typeface)) is a nice type-face on that resume.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch

The general outline isn't subject to change, only the number of mappings, and their specific class names. That can be indicated at runtime, hence why I'm slapping a cli on this. The run method has a limited, but slightly variable set of parameters.  Of which I know all possible combinations of, which I will add to the question.

Comment: I'm curious why you're writing code to do this and not using an existing tool that reads text files into a database.  If that's your specific application, trying to do this by hand feels like reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @markspace, I am using a tool to do the conversion, matter of fact, I didn't talk about that because I don't need help on how to do that.  I didn't write the classes I'm trying to use, it was autogenerated from said tool.

This question would be relevant no matter what methodology I select to use the classes. if I do it well, or if I write a pile of slop, the classes still do the mapping for me.

Comment: I don’t see where this is going to go anywhere productive. Voting to close as opinionated.

Answer (score -1):

As an experienced developer? I would say, let's do it the established way. Write a data source (API, files, clay tablets, etc.) consumer in a high-level language or script to extract and dump the data into staging tables whilst maintaining the existing structure, then take advantage of the declarative nature of SQL languages to write stored-procedures that transform and load the data how and where it needs to be.

... as an experienced developer

Comment: I didn't ask about how to map data, I'm already loading things from source to database and it wasn't a problem. You either know something about Java, or you don't.

Comment: I see you have edited your question. Anyway--- My point is, this is a solved problem in a market dominated by large vendors. Unless this is for education and your time is not valuable, use an existing solution (Datorama, Talend, etc.) If you really want to proceed, consider perusing the open-source ETL projects. But, you are heading the wrong way with auto-generated classes; instead, you need to abstract the mappings such that the cardinality support is built in. So, to answer your question, as an experienced developer, I would not approach this at all unless backed by significant investment.

Comment: I'm using mapforce, but that was not really the relevant part of the question.  Even if I used Talend, i'd end up with a pile of classes's would I not?

Comment: I am not sure about Talend. I still find automatic code generation for doing ETL an odd approach, but maybe I haven't come across a scenario where that is needed. (Currently, working on a BI project with 200+ data sources from very different technology stacks.)

Comment: A slightly older-school approach, would be a more valid point.  However it is far from odd, there is little to no difference between generating source code and using any other tool's provided class library. 

Almost every integration requires the glue to be programmed, I understand a sprawling enterprise with the expected mix of severe incompetence and inharent complexity, would gladly buy whatever they can do eliminate glue programming. However the price point for full service SAAS platforms is far from a joke.

I use SAAS, but those aren't available for everyone like Flow or Zapier.